# .NET 8 Upgrade and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.3.0

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, .net-8.0

**Problem:** We have an app on `.NET 6` and with the upcoming 11/4 deadline, we want to move onto `.NET 8`. When I upgraded the solution's projects, I only had one Nuget package that was flagged as `...not fully compatible with the project`and it was reverted to a legacy version. It was **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.3.0**

**Q:** Is there an alternative for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.3.0
that people are using for .NET 8, or is everyone just waiting for Microsoft to make it compatible with .NET 8?

**ScreenShot**

[image]
Thanks for any insight you guys can offer. Take care!

Comment: The whole `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` family appears to be .NET Framework specific. The `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package [only supports .NET Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core#supportedframeworks-body-tab) and there [are no .NET/.NET Standard search results](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi&frameworks=net%2Cnetstandard&prerel=true&sortby=relevance) for similar packages. Are you sure you're using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.3.0` with .NET 6?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing how it could be a transitive dependency, but `Microsoft.AspNet` appears to have been wholesale replaced by `Microsoft.AspNetCore` when .NET Core became the primary supported version of .NET.

Comment: Yes. It's auto reverting back to 5.3.0. I'll add a screenshot for the exact message I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED REPLY**: Since the Op clarified that he made a typo and wanted the library `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` I can reply that if you look [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core) you will see that similarly to the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` the latest version is `5.3.0` and it is from .NET **Framework** not core.

It just have a very unfortunate name, but a single google search would have pointed to the right direction. If you create a brand new MVC application (deprecated now in favor of Blazor web pages) you will see that it uses the`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace that comes included with .NET 8.

So basically you got confused by the library name and got yourself an incompatible .NET Framework nugget. The reason it works is because it is not used by the application and you get a warning for you to look it up.

Comment: Looks like I had a typo. It's not Cors. It's supposed to be Core, not Cors.